# programmatically setting Bootstrap radio button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a set of radio buttons using Bootstrap in javascript

The code I am trying is:

```
        var viewedFilterButtons = $("<div>").addClass("btn-group").attr("data-toggle", "buttons");
        viewedFilterButtons.append($("<label>").addClass("btn").addClass("btn-primary").append($("<input>").attr("id", "viewed-important").attr("type","radio").attr("name","viewed-filter").attr("value","important").attr("autocomplete","off").append($("<label for=\"viewed-important\">").text("Important"))));
        viewedFilterButtons.append($("<label>").addClass("btn").addClass("btn-primary").append($("<input>").attr("id", "viewed").attr("type","radio").attr("name","viewed-filter").attr("value","viewed").attr("autocomplete","off").text("Reviewed")));
```

(note that I'm trying 2 different things to get the text into the button -- in the first `input` I'm embedding a `label` and in the second I'm just trying to set the `text` of the `input`.  Neither is working right now.)

This generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input id="viewed-important" name="viewed-filter" value="important" autocomplete="off" type="radio">
      <label for="viewed-important">Important</label>
    </input>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="viewed" name="viewed-filter" value="viewed" autocomplete="off" type="radio">Reviewed
  </label>
</div>
```

Note that the input doesn't seem to be closed in the second case.  I'm getting this HTML from the Web Console Inspector in Firefox.

What I'm getting is a set of tiny radio buttons with no text.  The toggle behavior works fine.

What am I missing here?  When I manually generate a set of labels for radio buttons like this directly in the HTML it works fine.

```
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="viewed" name="viewed-filter" value="viewed" autocomplete="off" type="radio">Reviewed</input>
  </label>
```

Comment: I would suggest steering away from generating HTML from JavaScript. It is a nightmare to maintain. Consider using a templating tool like Handlebars.js instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you append the `<label>` inside the `<input/>`.

You're trying to do this :

`<input> <label>Important</label> </input>`

However, `<input/>` is a self-closing tag, not a container like a `<div>`.
You should design your structure like this :

`<label> <input/> Important </label>`

Comment: The HTML should either have the <input> within the label, or the `label` tag should use the `for` attribute to reference the input. It doesn't appear your structure does either.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I was missing something simple there!

Answer (score 0):

input elements cannot have children [w3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). Put the label after it.

```js
var viewedFilterButtons = $("#mainDiv").addClass("btn-group").attr("data-toggle", "buttons");
        
   var inputElem = $("<input>").attr("id", "viewed-important").attr("type","radio").attr("name","viewed-filter").attr("value","important").attr("autocomplete","off");
  
  viewedFilterButtons.append(inputElem)
                     .append($("<label for=\"viewed-important\">").addClass("btn").addClass("btn-primary").text("Important"));
```

```html
<link href="https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```